# Cloud Function doesn't work - Query and update firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The following function should receive a data from some documents' field. Then use that data while querying in another collection. After query it should update the docs. The code doesn't give any errors in editor but it doesn't work.

```
export const dailyTaskFunction2 = functions.pubsub
.schedule("0 0 * * *")
.timeZone("Europe/Istanbul")
.onRun(async () => {
  const users = await db
      .collection("users")
      .where("location", "==", "GMT+3")
      .get();
  const taskPromises = users.docs.map((doc) => {
    return db
        .collection("tasks")
        .where("dailyTasks", "==", true)
        .where("completed", "==", true)
        .where("userID", "==", doc.get("userID"))
        .get();
  });
  const taskDocs = await Promise.all(taskPromises);
  const actionsPromises = taskDocs.map((snapshots) => {
    return snapshots.docs.map((snapshot) => {
      return db
          .collection("tasks")
          .doc(snapshot.id)
          .set({completed: false}, {merge: true});
    });
  });
  await Promise.all(actionsPromises);
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on your syntax. The idea is clear but your are implementing it incorrectly.

Specially the part of:

```
const taskPromises = users.docs.map((doc) => {
    return db
        .collection("tasks")
        .where("dailyTasks", "==", true)
        .where("completed", "==", true)
        .where("userID", "==", doc.get("userID"))
        .get();
  });
```

You are returning multiple promises that are going to return different query snapshots, which you are pretending to concat on a single array.

Why don't you try to store promises on an array first. Also try to use `.catch()` to handle possible exceptions.

```
 export const dailyTaskFunction2 = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("Europe/Istanbul").onRun(async () => {
  const users = await db
      .collection("users")
      .where("location", "==", "GMT+3")
      .get();


  var taskPromises = []
  var taskDocs = []

  users.docs.map((doc) => {
    taskPromises.push(db
        .collection("tasks")
        .where("dailyTasks", "==", true)
        .where("completed", "==", true)
        .where("userID", "==", doc.get("userID"))
        .get().then((snapShot)=>{
            taskDocs = snapShot.concat(snapShot.docs);
            return;
        }))
  });

  await Promise.all(taskPromises).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e)
  });

  const actionsPromises = []
  
  taskDocs.map((snapshot) => {
    actionsPromises.push(db
        .collection("tasks")
        .doc(snapshot.id)
        .set({completed: false}, {merge: true}))
  });

  return Promise.all(actionsPromises).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e)
  });
});
```